# crash LAUNCH-FAILED Visual Studio Code

Tags: visual-studio-code

When I try to run Visual Studio Code, I get this error and I can't fix it. I have already proceeded to uninstall the application and its components and then install them again but nothing—I always get the same error:

> A window crash has occurred (reason: 'launch-failed')

Usually, as soon as I turn on the PC, it does not give me an error and runs the application quietly. If I try to open a new window or close the current one and reopen it, the error comes out.

[image]

Comment: Hi Maktia and welcome to the site! To have a higher change of getting a good reply, please provide more details about your version of Visual Studio Code and your operating system. Also, is the error message translated by you?

Comment: The Visual Studio Code version is 1.52.1. The Window version is "Windows 10 Home, 2004. I did not translate the error message, I think I not used the translator to post the question in the best way. The error message is in the image description. (LAUNCH-FAILED)